# My windows update failed with multiple errors

Tags: windows

I recently got a windows 11 update which never showed if it was compatible with my device so I downloaded it and it worked so I restarted it, switched it of and went to bed. The next day I woke up ate breakfast then got on my pc but it was blue screened. I tried all the methods but It wouldn’t work. Please help.

I tried my restore point and it would give errors, I tried reinstalling the pc and even that wouldn’t work. Please don’t give me wrong info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.